# Selected node changed

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, treeview

I have a treeview like this and I want to navigate to three different pages using `Response.Redirect`.

> → machine groups (main)
>
> →→ dept (parent)
>
> →→→ xyz (child)

```
protected void TreeView2_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TreeView2.SelectedValue == "Machine Groups")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Gridviewpage.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        switch (e.Node.Depth)
        {
            case 0:
                Response.Redirect("~/Machineupdate.aspx?node=" + TreeView2.SelectedNode.Value);
                break;

            case 1:
                Response.Redirect("~/MachineUpdatechild.aspx?node=" + TreeView3.SelectedNode.Value);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now if I put `EventArgs` it points to an error on `e.Node` that `System.EventArgs` does not contain definition for `Node`.

If i replace `EventArgs` with `TreeNodeEventArgs`, then that error goes away but I get an error on compilation:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0123: No overload for 'TreeView2_SelectedNodeChanged' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView2" runat="server"  OnUnload="TreeViewMain_Unload" 
    ontreenodepopulate="TreeView2_TreeNodePopulate" 
    onselectednodechanged="TreeView2_SelectedNodeChanged">
    <Nodes>
        <asp:TreeNode PopulateOnDemand="True" Text="Machine Groups"
            Value="Machine Groups"></asp:TreeNode>
    </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

Please help  me out.

I would also like to know what is the difference between `EventArgs` and `TreeNodeEventArgs`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, this looks like one of those poor API issues... I would think it reasonable to pass more specific event args here too!

One thing to look at is instead of trying to get the selected node from the event args, try
doing the switch on the selected node with TreeView2.SelectedNode.

It looks like you were halfway there already, because you are using that proprerty later on. So, I don't know if there might be an issue you've already found with that but don't mention itabove.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, I had it working before using `TreeNodeEventArgs`, but you can get away with doing `EventArgs` and then just `yourTreeView.SelectedNode` depending on what you have to do...